# Reading the directory structure of a GitHub project in Java

Tags: java, github

For a unique test scenario I have, I need to be able to read the directory structure of a given Github project (public project) in Java. In other words, given a GitHub project url, my program should be able to read the Java files under `/src/main/java`.

Option 1: Reading the html directly from a url like below and parsing for certain tokens is one option, but it is too brittle and painful.

`https://github.com/testuser/testproject/tree/master/src/main/java`

Option 2: Download the project as zip file and using Java [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) to process it.

`https://github.com/testuser/testproject/archive/master.zip`

Other than these 2 options, are there any simpler solutions that I'm missing?

Comment: Other options: implement a git client ;)

Comment: Or use an existing one: http://developer.github.com/libraries/

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use [Kohsuke's GitHub API For Java](http://github-api.kohsuke.org/index.html) from the list of libraries mentioned in [developer.github.com/libraries]. I'm able to connect to a public repository and get [GHBranch](http://github-api.kohsuke.org/apidocs/index.html) object. However, I can't find any clue to pull the file/directory listings. I've sent an email to the author of the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't get the Java GitHub library to work, I decided to parse the source zip file to get what I wanted.

```
    String githubZip = "https://github.com/testuser/testproject/archive/master.zip"

    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = null
    def javaFiles = [:]
    try {
        zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new URL(githubZip).openStream());
        ZipEntry zipEntry;

        while( (zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry())!=null ) {
            if(!zipEntry.isDirectory() && zipEntry.getName().endsWith("java")){
                StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()
                IOUtils.copy(zipInputStream, stringWriter)
                def fileContent = stringWriter.toString();

                javaFiles[zipEntry.getName()] = fileContent
                stringWriter.close()
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        zipInputStream.close()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `JGit` library to clone the repository onto your filesystem, and then traverse the working directory in the normal way - because it's just a regular directory.

Comment: Thanks Robin. As mentioned by Dave Newton, if I succeed using one of the GitHub Java APIs in develop.github.com/libraries, then that is the ideal solution for my case. I want to avoid cloning the repository to the file system, since I may not have access permissions in the external build system.